# Power saving control of CPU

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, power-management, powertop, pm-utils

My notebok is Asus U36SD and I've upgraded from 12.04 to 16.04. There was the `Jupiter` program in Ubuntu 12.04 which was able to drastically change the computer performance
 - when set to powersave, the machine was notably slow, probably lowering also the CPU frequency and other tweaks; the `PowerTop` showed average discharge rate of max. 10 W.

Now, with 16.04 (where `Jupiter` is not supported anymore (?)), using `PowerTop`, `pm-powersav`, `cpufrequtils` and `tlp` I still reach the  discharge rate of at least 16W in the powersave mode. Actually, the machine is still pretty fast - looking at cpufreq-info, it keeps the minimum frequency (800 MHz) of all four cores only when "nothing happens"; as soon as I play a video, frequencies run up to 2.3 GHz.

Is there any other powersaving utility, that can really force the computer to - even at the cost of slowing down the machine - save power?